# How to show pages index in side when showing the pdf in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

[image]

In the above image, we can see the navigationbar and pages index(side) which can viewed when the user tapped the screen once and will be removed from superview, on another tap.

I added the navigationbar using tap gesture recogniser, but to show the pages index I didn't know what to do and even **how to search in google**?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Comment: or... maybe you will have success with simple UIViewController http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added the `uiwebview`tag to your question, I guess you are using a `uiwebview` to read the pdf.
In this case, there is no way to add a sidebar with the page index.
The only way do it is to develop your own viewer using [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-CJBDCGCB), or to use an existing library.

Comment: are u sure,there is no way to show the side page index when showing the pdf in uiwebview